# Finding the remainder of $823^{823}$ in the division by 11

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I wish to find the remainder $823^{823}$ in the division by $11$.

I used the  Euler-Fermat theorem  that tells that: $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1$ $(\mod n)$, whenever $(a,n) =1$
First, Euler- Fermat tells us that $a^{\phi(11)} \equiv 1 (\mod 11)$ whenever $a$ is coprime with to 11. Since 823 is prime, we have, $(823,11) = 1$.
Now $823 \equiv 9 (\mod 11)$

But I don't know how to continue.. Because both $823$ and $11$ are prime ; do I have to use Fermat's little theorem?

Any help appreciated

Comment: It doesn't really matter that $823$ is prime.  As you (correctly) point out $823^n\equiv 9^n \pmod {11}$.  So now apply Little Fermat to $9^{823}\pmod {11}$.

Comment: The relevant prime here is 11, so, you can reduce the exponent Mod 10

Comment: Fermat's little theorem is a special case of the Euler-Fermat theorem when $n$ is prime

Answer (score 3):

Note that you also have $823\equiv -2\mod11$, which will make calculating powers by hand easier. Now by *lil' Fermat*,
$$823^{823}\equiv (-2)^{823\bmod 10}=-8\equiv 3\mod 11.$$

Answer (score -2):

Note that $$823^5\equiv 1 \mod 11$$ and then you can square the equation.